# The latter mock.patch() does not work

Tags: python, mocking

See the following code

### mock-test/ymath.py

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

### mock-test/calc.py

```
from ymath import add

def calc(x, y):
    return add(x, y)
```

### mock-test/main.py

```
import mock


class YAdd:
    def __init__(self, a):
        print 'YAdd init with a %s' % (a, )
        self.a = a

    def __call__(self, x, y, **kwargs):
        return x + y + self.a


def calc(x, y):
    print 'calc called...'

    @mock.patch('ymath.add', YAdd(x))
    def inner():
        from calc import calc
        print calc(x, y)
    inner()


calc(8, 3)  # Expected: 8 + 8 + 3 = 19
calc(4, 5)  # Expected: 4 + 4 + 5 = 13
```

The result as following shown, the expected value of the second invoke was 13

```
calc called...

YAdd init with a 8

19

calc called...

YAdd init with a 4

17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're patching in the wrong place. You should be patching `calc.add`, not `ymath.add`. See the docs on [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

Note also there's no reason to define an inner function just to use the patch decorator: you can use it as a context manager instead.

```
def calc(x, y):
    print 'calc called...'

    with mock.patch('calc.add', YAdd(x)):
        from calc import calc
        print calc(x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I also want to know why the second invoke does not work. By the way, using an inner function makes code more clean when patching multiple objects

Comment: And I hope to patch `ymath.add` directly, since in a more complex scenario, the method would be used in multiple modules. I hope the patch could work in all place.